# Is Fisher's discriminant analysis equivalent to the Bayes optimal LDA when the no. of classes is greater than two and covariances are all equal?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, least-squares, discriminant-analysis, bayes-optimal-classifier

P.S. While I gave a brief background to make the question complete, **informed readers can move to the questions 1 and 2 towards the end of this post, right after 'what are not clear to me are:'**.

**Fisher's discriminant analysis for two classes:** Let's assume that we've data in $\mathbb{R}^d$ from $2$ classes with means $\mu_0, \mu_1$ and covariances $\Sigma_0, \Sigma_1$ respectively, $d > 2$ and that we're performing Fisher's discriminant analysis (FDA for short, not a standard abbreviation) that finds the optimal line $\mathbb{R}^d$ passing through the origin, so that projections of the given data onto this subspace are 'optimally separated', i.e. the ratio of the between-class variance of the projection onto $w$ to the within-class variance of the projection onto $w$ is maximal; so mathematically copying from [Wikipidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#:%7E:text=Linear%20discriminant%20analysis%20(LDA)%2C,classes%20of%20objects%20or%20events.):

[image]

is maximal w.r.t. $w,$ and it's well known that

[image]

Now consider the homoscedasticity assumption, i.e. $\Sigma_0=\Sigma_1=\Sigma.$ In this case, we can see that $w\propto \Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0).$

**Linear Discriminant Anslysis (LDA) for two classes:** In this case, the goal is to perform a two-class classification and thus find a linear decision boundary between the two sets of data. We [know that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#:%7E:text=Linear%20discriminant%20analysis%20(LDA)%2C,classes%20of%20objects%20or%20events.) (see the section "LDA for two classes") in this case, we can have this decision boundary is given by:

$$\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: w^{T}x=c\}$$

where:

[image]

Given the above analysis for the two-class case, we note that **the decision boundary from LDA is orthogonal to the optimal direction of projection in FDA, and FDA and LDA can be deemed equivalent in this case**.

**My question is:** Are there any results that generalize this to the $K>2$ class FDA and LDA?

A brief mathematical analysis for the same is given on the same Wiki page, or also in [this book](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf), P. 191-192, section 4.1.6, equation (4.51) where this time, instead of one direction, we look for a vector subspace of dimension $d'<d,$ and the optimal solution is given by maximizing

[image]

The paragraph after equation (4.51) explains why $d'\le k-1$ using a rank argument, which is clear. **But what are not clear to me are:**

1. What's the **formulation of Bayes' optimal multiclass LDA as a linear classifier under homoscedasticity**? Could you cite a resource, as I was unable to find it in neither the Wiki nor the book I mentioned above.
2. **Is there a subspace of dimension $d-d'$ arising from the multiclass Bayes' optimal LDA, that's perpendicular/orthogonal to the optimal subspace $W_{opt}$ of dimension $d'$ arising from multiclass FDA, mentioned above?** I took a look at [this](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jol2/course/stat597e/notes2/lda.pdf) as a resource, and on P.8, they derive the equation to the decision boundary between class $k, l, k\ne l,$ but this is of dimension $d-1 > d-d',$ so this isn't the subspace $W_{opt}.$

Thank you for any directions and resources!